# Select ordering works differently on windows and in container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, containers, jooq

I'm facing problem with ordering database records. I'm using jOOQ and DSLContext in SpringBoot application to select data from configured Oracle database. Everything works fine locally on my Windows device. After deploying application to Openshift container platform, the same select orders records differently. Database contains text values in Slovak language with accents and special characters as you can see in result tables.

**Select:**

```sql
var companies = DSLContext.select().from(Company.COMPANY)
                                   .orderBy(Company.NAME)
                                   .fetch()
                                   .stream()
                                   .map(this::mapCompany)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Result on Windows: (good result)**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Aaaa |
| 2 | Áááá |
| 3 | Bbbb |
| 4 | "Bcbb" |
| 5 | "Ccccc" |

**Result on deployed app: (wrong result)**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Bcbb" |
| 2 | "Ccccc" |
| 3 | Aaaa |
| 4 | Áááá |
| 5 | Bbbb |

I think that problem is caused by different locale or encoding on windows and container(unix). The application is deploying using dockerfile. Can anyone provide some solution, how to achieve the same behavior in container as in Windows?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle database.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have the same locale. You could set the default locale in your application or you could set the locale per request

Comment: I tried to set spring.web.locale=sk_SK and spring.web.locale-resolver=fixed, but result was without any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jOOQ API supports [collations](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/collations/), which is the SQL way of specifying the sort order for different character sets and locales. You could write:

```java
var companies = DSLContext.select().from(Company.COMPANY)
                                   .orderBy(Company.NAME.collate(myCollation))
                                   .fetch(this::mapCompany)
```

But this is only really a good idea if you're not in control of your database collations. Otherwise, better specify them with your table definitions, or when you set up your database. Please refer to your database manual for details on how to deal with collations.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was struggling for a while because of incorrect collation name. I was trying to pass _Slovak_CI_AS_ instead of _Slovak_CI_ (option for case-insensitive).  Actual Oracle supported collations can be found here: [Link to Oracle collation list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#Server-level-collations)